# virtual functions and static_cast

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

Can i safely call virtual functions after using static_cast on polymorphic class in situations like in the following code or is it UB?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo() \n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo() \n"; }
};

int main()
{
   Base* derived = new Derived;
   Derived* _1 = static_cast<Derived*>(derived);
   _1->foo();
}
```

Comment: I think, the question made more sense if you made `foo()` non-virtual.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. Although I don't see the point of doing that in your specific example. Just calling it as

```
derived->foo();
```

without any casts would have produced exactly the same effect. I.e. some sort of `static_cast` in that case would be performed implicitly by the virtual call mechanism.

Note that your `static_cast` does not in any way suppress the "virtual" nature of the call.

That actually makes me wonder what your question is really about. Why would you even ask about it? What are you trying to do? In your code sample really representative of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Why doesn't `static_cast` suppress the virtual nature of the call ?

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler allows you to `static_cast` and at run-time the dynamic type of the object is as expected, then yes, you can. The question is why do you want to do that...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but as others have said, you don't need to cast the pointer to the derived type to call virtual functions.

However, it is usually safer to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) when dealing with inherited classes. Using `dynamic_cast` will generate the proper errors if the type information is incorrect at runtime.

```
Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(derived); //safer, but still unnecessary in this situation
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, that's going to work, basically because `derived` *is* a `Derived*`. So, all the cast is doing is telling the compiler what you already know. Then again, even without the static cast, you'll just end up with `Derived::foo` in your output. So, this is somewhat pointless. Still, you might need to do this in a situation where you're absolutely sure you know the actual instanced type of your variable and you need to access some non-virtual members for some reason. If you're using a badly designed class library, for instance...

But, in general, static downcasts are a bad idea. You might end up trying to downcast a variable that *isn't* a `Derived*`, in which case, calling virtual (or non-virtual) functions (or, in fact, using that pointer for almost any non-trivial operation) results in Undefined Behavior.