# How does static_cast affect the virtual function calls?

Tags: c++

I have the following code (stolen from [virtual functions and static_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016653/virtual-functions-and-static-cast)):

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo() \n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo() \n"; }
};
```

If I have:

```
int main()
{
   Base base;
   Derived& _1 = static_cast<Derived&>(base);
   _1.foo();
}
```

The print-out will be: `Base::foo()`

However, if I have:

```
int main()
{
   Base * base;
   Derived* _1 = static_cast<Derived*>(base);
   _1->foo();
}
```

The print-out will be: `Segmentation fault: 11`

Honestly, I don't quite understand both. Can somebody explain the complications between static_cast and virtual methods based on the above examples? BTW, what could I do if I want the print-out to be "`Derived::foo()`"?

Comment: If you make a call on an uninitialized pointer, a segmentation fault is actually the best-case outcome.

Comment: For the print-out to be Derived::foo(), you would need to ensure an instantiation of a Derived type exists, which it does not in either example.

Comment: You segfault with the pointers because you don't have any actual objects.  Just pointers that don't point to any yet.  So `_1->foo()` tries to read a virtual table from a random memory location.  If you change the pointers to `Base base; Derived *_1 = static_cast<Derived*>(&base);` then you can try calling `foo()` but you should still get `Base::foo()` because that is what the object is.  To get `Derived::foo()` you need a `Derived _2; _2.foo()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example, you segfault because you did not instanciate your base pointer. So there is no v-table to call. Try:

```
Base * base = new Base();
Derived* _1 = static_cast<Derived*>(base);
_1->foo();
```

This will print Base::foo()

The question makes no sense, as the static_cast will not affect the v-table. However, this makes more sens with non-virtual functions :

```
class Base
{
public:
   void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo() \n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo() \n"; }
};


int main()
{
   Base base;
   Derived& _1 = static_cast<Derived&>(base);
   _1.foo();
}
```

This one will output Derived::foo(). This is however a **very wrong code**, and though it compiles, the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: This example is still broken. It is illegal to cast `Base &` to `Derived &` when the source reference is not referring to a [sub-]object of `Derived` type. The behavior is undefined in your example.

Comment: It may be illegal and yes, I guess its undefined, so maybe it does not have its place in the answer. But one could ask himself why this does compile and give this output nonetheless. I'll edit the answer, thx.

Answer (score 6):

A valid `static_cast` to pointer or reference type does not affect virtual calls at all. Virtual calls are resolved in accordance with the dynamic type of the object. `static_cast` to pointer or reference does not change the dynamic type of the actual object.

The output you observe in your examples is irrelevant though. The examples are simply broken.

The first one makes an invalid `static_cast`. You are not allowed to cast `Base &` to `Derived &` in situations when the underlying object is not `Derived`. Any attempt to perform such cast produces undefined behavior.

Here's an example of valid application of `static_cast` for reference type downcasting

```
int main()
{
   Derived derived;
   Base &base = derived;
   Derived& _1 = static_cast<Derived&>(base);
   _1.foo();
}
```

In your second example the code is completely broken for reasons that have nothing to do with any casts or virtual calls. The code attempts to manipulate non-initialized pointers - the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The whole purpose of virtual functions is that the static type of the variable shouldn't matter. The compiler will look up the actual implementation for the object itself (usually with a vtable pointer hidden within the object). `static_cast` should have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

In both examples the behavior is undefined. A `Base` object is not a `Derived` object, and telling the compiler to pretend that it is doesn't make it one. The way to get the code to print out `"Derived::foo()"` is to use an object of type `Derived`.