# static_cast - Why is it working here?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I have the following code snippet

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "Base MyMethod" << "\n";
    }
};


class der : public base
{
public:
    virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived MyMethod" << "\n";
    }
};


void foo(base* b)
{
    der* d = static_cast<der*>(b);
    d->MyMethod();
}

int main()
{
    base* b = new der();
    foo(b);
}
```

Now my question is why is static_Cast working here. I read that static_casts cannot cast through polymorphic types. so why is the above example working - Am I missing something here ? I was expecting that dynamic cast could only resolve such an issue since they should be used with polymorphic types ? Could anyone give an example where static cast would fail and dynamic cast would pass ?

Comment: You're not using virtual inheritance... `class der : public virtual base` would be virtual inheritance.

Comment: Take out the `static_cast`.. you get the same result.

Comment: `static_cast` is fine as long as you know the dynamic type.

Comment: @vanza I meant polymorphic types

Comment: It already is a `der`. So you aren't doing anything novel here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016653/virtual-functions-and-static-cast

Comment: @staticx Take out the `static_cast`, and you get a compile-time error.

Comment: @hvd: Not if you change it to `b->MyMethod()` http://ideone.com/HNRZYL

Comment: @staticx Taking out the `static_cast` would make it `der* d = b;`, which is an error. You meant taking out the entire line with the `static_cast`? Okay, yes, that would work, but that no longer is relevant to this question, IMO.

Comment: @hvd: I think it was pretty clear..

Comment: @staticx If you were as clear as you thought, I wouldn't have misunderstood. :)

Comment: @hvd: You knew what I meant. It was clear. Do you have anything else to add?

Comment: Dont understand why the downvote. I am merely trying to understand situations in which a static_cast would not do a job

Comment: @staticx No, I didn't. My first thought was that you were using some compiler which makes the diagnostic for an invalid conversion non-fatal, and were ignoring the warning you got. And if you claim, after I stated that I misunderstood your comment, that I did understand, I fail to see how I can read that as anything other than a claim that I'm lying and wasting your time, which would be rude and completely uncalled for. Or did I misunderstand you again? If not, I'll refrain from commenting further.

Comment: @hvd: I suppose it would work if you did `der* d = (der*)b;`. Frankly, I think you are being unnecessarily pedantic. The only person who it would be unclear to would be the OP, which he didn't comment. I don't think you are lying, just being coy. The reason I originally pointed out to remove the `static_cast` was to prove to OP that it was useless. Comments are meant to be short and sweet. Not entirely detailed like an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> “Now my question is why is `static_cast` working here.”

There is no reason why it should not work. The types are related by class derivation, and that’s known by the compiler. Essentially `static_cast` is restricted to do or undo any implicit conversion, and you do have an implicit conversion from `der*` to `base*`.

> “I read that `static_cast`s cannot cast through polymorphic types.”

That’s just balderdash.

> “[snip] Could anyone give an example where `static cast` would fail and `dynamic cast` would pass?”

```
struct A { virtual ~A(){} };
struct B { virtual ~B(){} };

struct T: A, B {};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    T o;
    A& oA = o;
    //B& oB = static_cast<B&>( oA );    //! This won't compile, unrelated types.
    B& oB = dynamic_cast<B&>( oA );
}
```

Comment: static_cast performs a cast which occurs at compile-time and has a well-defined behavior.

Comment: @NeilKirk: a `static_cast` can involve an address adjustment, which in some (most) cases necessarily happens at runtime. also, casting between number types generally changes the bitpattern, again with many (most) cases at runtime. but yes it's well-defined.

Comment: Using the same question sample, but let `class der : public virtual base` then using static_cast will fail, and using dynamic_cast will succeed

Comment: @humam: regarding the `static_cast` failure (or that it won't compile), right, because the known `base` object might have other sub-objects than `der` that derive virtually from `base`. that would make the address computation unknown at compile time. but regarding "dynamic_cast will succeed`, that depends on the actual object pointed to. one would not be very happy if the `dynamic_cast` *arbitrarily* selected one particular `der` sub-object, and instead of giving a specific, complicated rule for the selection, it just fails when there is more than one possibility.

Answer (score 3):

Usually dynamic_cast is used, to cast a base pointer to a derived pointer. This is because the object pointed to by base, may not actually be the derived type. So dynamic_cast performs a run-time check, and returns a null pointer if the object is incompatible.

But this run-time check has a slight performance cost. If you are totally sure in the logic of your program, that the cast will succeed, you can use a static_cast instead and prevent the run-time check. But if you get the object type wrong, you will get undefined behavior.